# Replace request body in NGINX proxy for POST

Tags: nginx, proxy

I'm trying to use NGINX to proxy a request that needs to do a bit of magic in the middle.  Essentially I have a client that can only send an unauthenticated GET request, and I need to receive this request, make a POST that will login to a server using static credentials stored in the NGINX config, and replace the response body with an html redirect.  This will work for my scenario because the POST response will contain a Set-Cookie header with a session id representing the authenticated session.  I know I can use `proxy_method` to force NGINX to make the outbound call via POST, and I can use `sub_filter` to replace the POST response with the html redirect.  My question is how can I set a request body that will get sent in the POST request?

Any ideas?

Ian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent a lot of time researching this a while back and the best solution seemed to be using Lua.  It's a bit of a pain.  I had to compile NGINX with Lua.  I used [OpenResty](http://openresty.org).  My use-case required masking sensitive data posted through my NGINX reverse proxy.  However its definitely different than yours in that you're using proxy_method to make the additional POST so I'm not 100% it will solve your problem.  However, I think it's worth checking out.  Here is a small code snippet from my config if it helps.  Glad to go into more detail if you need.

```
location /login {
    set $request_body_mask "";

        # mask client_secret in posts
        access_by_lua '
            local req = ngx.req.get_body_data()
        ngx.var.request_body_mask = ngx.re.gsub(req, "(client_secret=).{8}", "$1********")
    ';

    # mask client_secret in gets
    set_by_lua $request_mask '
        local req = ngx.var.request_uri
        return ngx.re.gsub(req, "(client_secret=).{8}", "$1********")
    ';
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.  That's pretty much what I'd concluded too.  I might choose to write a module to do this instead.

Comment: Do I need to change anything in log format. as of now I am using $request_body. But after applying the above code its not logging anything

Comment: Have't looked at this code in years.  This is what I have:

    # added to log entire request and response bodies with lua
    log_format bodylog '$remote_addr $http_client_ip_address - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                      '"$http_source_environment" "SUUID=$http_Session_UUID" '
                      '$request_time $upstream_response_time $pipe '
                      '<"$request_body" >"$resp_body"';

Answer (score 4):

## Working example for Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 18.04

[image]

### Installation

```
# sudo apt purge nginx-*  # maybe necessary, backup your /etc/nginx/… configs before!
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
sudo apt-cache show nginx-extras | grep -E '(xenial|bionic)'
sudo apt install nginx-extras  # Lua support (nginx-extras is > nginx-full)
```

### Config

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/test.conf`

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name test.example.com;

    location /
    {
        if ($request_method = POST)
        {
            access_by_lua_block
            {
                ngx.req.read_body()
                local req = ngx.req.get_body_data()
                local newreq, n, err = ngx.re.gsub(req, "REPLACE", "REPLACED")
                ngx.req.set_body_data(newreq)
            }
        }

        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://target.local:80/;
    }
}
```

### Activate

```
cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
sudo ln -s ../sites-available/test.conf test.conf
sudo nginx -t
sudo service nginx reload  # or newer: sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

If there are no `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` folders, simply put `test.conf` in your `conf.d` folder.

Comment: It worked! for docker container it must be compile with "--with-luajit \"