# Add custom JSON Body to forwarded Nginx request

Tags: rest, http, nginx, python-requests, proxy

I have a `Service A` sitting behind `NGINX` acting as reverse proxy (for http basic auth). The request path is:

`Client > NGINX > Service A`

My nginx.conf is:

```
events {}
http {
    server {
        listen       19202;
        server_name  localhost;

        auth_basic           "Restricted Area";
        auth_basic_user_file /tmp/htpasswd;


        location /api/v1/proxy/info {
            proxy_pass http://api:39999;
            allow all;
        }
}
```

Now I would like to extend the config so whenever request to location `/api/v1/proxy/info` is forwarded, it should contain JSON Body (application/json MIME) that was added by NGINX (client will send bare GET request w/o any body, it will be appended by nginx).

`Client (no JSON Body) > NGINX (add JSON Body) > Service A`

How can I easily achieve this?

Comment: I believe Lua could help you with that I found this question to help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614199/replace-request-body-in-nginx-proxy-for-post